# Merge from upstream using the GitHub Api

Tags: github

It doesn't look like I can merge commits from an upstream repo using the github api:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/

I would like the `base` parameter to be a branch from someone else's fork. I've tried POSTing with base as "`otheruser/master`" and "`otheruser:master`". Is there no way to merge across forks at this endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the `merge` api only supports combining of branches in the same repository.

I think you want to make a pull request.
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls

The pull request must be made in/from the `repository` the changes will be pulled into. In your case the endpoint would look something like this

`/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls`

`:owner` would be the `otheruser`

`:repo` would be the name of their fork

As stated in the documentation this is a `POST`. In the body you would specify your branch as the `head` like this `<username>:<branch name>`. The `base` should just be the name of the branch. The `base` only needs to be the name of the branch because the pull request is being made in the repository that has the `base` branch.

Comment: How would making a PR help me in this case? a PR aleady exists from the fork to my repo, I would like to update the fork's codebase with master using GithubApi

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `refs`

https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference

The request would look like this:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<fork-owner>/<fork-repo>/git/refs/heads/<forked-branch-name>
```

The body would look like this:

```
{
  "sha": <master-sha-in-origin-repo>,
  "force": true
}
```

**Watch out!!!** .

If there is a Pull-Request open between the fork and the original, it will close the PR and run over the commits